# Install PyPy globally Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pypy

I want to install PyPy on my Ubuntu and I want it to be installed system-wide so I could call PyPy in terminal everywhere like: `pypy main.py`. I also want to have standard python and pip available.

I'm not a very experienced Linux user yet so I'm lost.

Comment: what about using an alias?

Comment: There is an installable `pypy` package. I don't know exactly what it provides.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @keith-thompson says, you can do `sudo apt install pypy pypy-dev`. If you want a more up-to-date version you can do `snap install pypy pypy-dev`. Another way to get a working environment is to use conda, as per [this link](https://conda-forge.org/blog/2020/03/10/pypy). The advantage of conda is that you can easily install pre-built packages such as numpy, sciy (coming soon), and more. If you use the first recipes, `pip install` will currently have to build many packages from source.

Note that `pip` is never "available anywhere", it is tied to the particular python instance, and installs packages into a path for that specific instance. Thus the `pip` you use for python2 is different than the `pip` you use for python3, likewise for pypy.